# How to fix RapidClipse4 org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not configure overrides from file: hibernate.reveng.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, rapidclipse

I am still working with RapidClipse 4 around 3 month. 
I am also a newby with java, eclipse and related things and still trying to learn by doing.

My project is still growing up and worked fine until, suddenly I got following error while trying to import a MySQL table: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not configure overrides from file: hibernate.reveng.xml
In detail:

````
    org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not configure overrides from file: Y:\workspace\RC_07\launcher\hibernate.reveng.xml
    at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.OverrideRepository.addFile(OverrideRepository.java:144)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.common.Util.invokeMethod(Util.java:43)
    at org.jboss.tools.hibernate.runtime.common.AbstractOverrideRepositoryFacade.addFile(AbstractOverrideRepositoryFacade.java:21)
    at com.rapidclipse.datatools.hibernate.metadata.MetadataUtils.lambda$1(MetadataUtils.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.console.execution.DefaultExecutionContext.execute(DefaultExecutionContext.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.execute(ConsoleConfiguration.java:107)
    at com.rapidclipse.datatools.hibernate.metadata.MetadataUtils.readDatabaseMetadata(MetadataUtils.java:139)
    at com.rapidclipse.frameworktools.core.ui.wizard.generateentities.AssociationsWizardPage.init(AssociationsWizardPage.java:883)
    at com.rapidclipse.frameworktools.core.ui.wizard.generateentities.AssociationsWizardPage.lambda$2(AssociationsWizardPage.java:822)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2292)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2319)
    at com.rapidclipse.frameworktools.core.ui.wizard.generateentities.AssociationsWizardPage.lambda$3(AssociationsWizardPage.java:829)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid override definition
    at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.OverrideRepository.addInputStream(OverrideRepository.java:190)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.OverrideRepository.addFile(OverrideRepository.java:139)
    ... 16 more
    ```

I read a lot regarding this, also in stackoverflow. 
But I am not able to translate what I read into a solution, which fixes the problem.


Creating a new project did not fix the problem.

Which leeds me to the assumption that it is still caused by Win10 and an installation of libreOffice.base - which I did few days ago, which required to install an other MySQl connector.

Manual edit of hibernate.reveng.xml did still not work, because RapidClipse still overwrites the changes. and creates everything automaticaly.

Reinstalling RapidClipse 4.0, and the project did also not fix it.

Would someone help me to fix this problem, or give me some hints how to figure out a solution?

Any idea? 
Any additional information, which I should provide?

Thank you in advance 
rgds OpaHeinz
````

Comment: I figured out, that on my C-Drive and in my project workspace, there is no hibernate.cfg.xml

Answer (score 0):

Rapidclipse fixing the problem. There is problem in DTD file hosted on sourceforge.

Answer (score 0):

**This issue is fixed, Download new version of Rapidclipse 4.0.1 **

Comment: Thank you very much Prashant, this sounds wonderfull!
But I installed the new version and after trying to start, I got an error message.
I will analyse tommorow and come back with solution or with details.
have a nice day

Comment: Cool no problem. I did same and it working. I think the only change that made in this version is they fixed "hibernate.reveng.xml" issue. Still you can see the log in the workspace in .metdata/.log file

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this helped fine!
The error I got, was just an onetime Error. 
After updating everything worked fine again

@Prashant:  Thank you very much 
OpaHeinz